# rate widget showing 403 error when anonymous submitting vote

Tags: 6, nodes, rating

I have added rate widget as five star to content type. I have set permission for rate widget that only 'authenticated user' can vote and 'Redirect to login form' for the anonymous user.

I want to display rate widget in right side bar, so I created a custom module to display rate widget in block.

I have also set "Do not add automatically" setting for rate widget in admin.

I have implemented hook `hook_block()` into module and creating the block.

Code Snippets for block body

```
$node = menu_get_object();

    $output = '';

    if ($node->type == 'primary_antibodies') {

        $output = ' <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                 <tr>
                <td width="100%" class="normalfontbold">
                  <h3>
                 <font size="+1" face="Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif" color="#a94b91">Rate this product</font>
                  </h3>
                </td>               
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td class="normalfont">Is working as
                  expected:</td></tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>' . $node->rate_field_pr_prab_rate_expected['#value'] . '
                </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td class="normalfont">Product
                  documentation:</td></tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>' . $node->rate_field_pr_prab_rate_documentation['#value'] . '
                </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td class="normalfont">Product quality:</td></tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>' . $node->rate_field_pr_prab_rate_quality['#value']. '
                </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td class="normalfont">Service:</td></tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>'  . $node->rate_field_pr_prab_rate_service['#value'] . '
                </td>
                 </tr>
                 </tbody>
                 </table>';

    }
return $output;
```

When any anonymous user trying to vote, its showing '403 error'. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: 403 means user does not have permission to do this. Pretty common for anonymous. Does this module provide "rate" permission you can add to anon?

Comment: I have setting for rate widget that 'Redirect to login page' for anonymous user. But, its not redirecting.

Comment: Please show code of your custom module, then, as it seems that it disabled this feature by accident.

Comment: @Mołot I have updated the question.